# Construct an alternating series such that $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ converge but $\sum (-1)^n a_n^3$ diverge where $a_n>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

if I write it as the follow:

$a_1-a_2+a_3-a_4...$ converge but $a_1^3-a_2^3+a_3^3-a_4^3...$ diverge

What I have thought is that by making the odd term($a_{2k+1}^3$) a diverge series like $1,\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{5}...$,
and the even term($a_{2k}^3$) as something converge with a smaller order such as $\frac{1}{2^3},\frac{1}{4^3}...$, then $\sum (-1)^n a_n^3=1-\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4^3}...$ would be a diverge series, but I can not come up with a satisfactory result to make the original series converge

Hope you could help

Comment: Do you know for a fact that there is such a series? How?

Comment: *Hint* There exists $a,b,c,d>0$ such that $a-b+c-d=0$ but $a^3-b^3+c^3-d^3>0$.

Comment: I did not check the existence, because this is an exercise from an online course lecture notes, I think from the description of the exercise it seems to suppose it does exist.

Comment: @yleswill What happened to the numerators?

Comment: @user10354138 Sorry I make a mistake it should be $\sum a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{n}}+\frac{4}{\sqrt[3]{n}}-\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$ and $\sum a_n^3=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{8}{n}+\frac{64}{n}-\frac{27}{n}$ Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following sequence for $n \geq 0$:
\begin{align*}
x_{4n} = x_{4n+2} &= \frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{n+1}}\\
x_{4n+1} &= \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{n+1}}\\
x_{4n+3} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n+1}}
\end{align*}
Then $\sum (-1)^n x_n$ converges to $0$ whereas $\sum (-1)^n x_n^3$ diverges since $$x_{4n}^3 - x_{4n+1}^3 + x_{4n+2}^3 - x_{4n+3}^3 = -\frac{12}{n+1}.$$